# Determine whether if T where $T:P_2\to P_2$ defined by $T(a+bx+cx^2)=a+b(x+1)+b(x+1)^2$ is linear and then prove.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Determine whether if T where $T:P_2\to P_2$ defined by $T(a+bx+cx^2)=a+b(x+1)+b(x+1)^2$ is linear and then prove.

So I know I can either use definition of linear transformation or turn it into a matrix transformation which is thus linear. I don't know how to prove by definition though. Would I just define $u=d+ex+fx^2$ and $v=g+hx+kx^2$ and let $m$ be a scalar, all without loss of generality, and then just plug in to show that $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ and $T(mu)=mT(u)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to prove.

Comment: Instead of $u,v$ and random variable names that can cause errors, I’d use $$p_1(x)=a_1+b_1x+c_1x^2\\ p_2(x)=a_2+b_2x+c_2x^2$$ But there is nothing wrong with your start.